# How does android loads an activity on screen?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-manifest

In my application i have created an activity which is showing simple hello world message.
In "AndroidManifest.xml" file i set label attribute as="welcome":

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.dmo.MainActivity"
    android:label="Welcome" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

in in `MainActivity.java` file in `onCreate()` method I set the title of an activity as "Hello world" using `setTitle("Hello World ");`

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        setTitle("Hello World .");
    }
```

Now my issue is that  . . When I run my app First of all only title bar is shown with title set as "Welcome" i.e. set from `androidManifest.xml` file . . Then after the delay of some miliseconds remaining GUI is displayed and title changes to "Hello World" i.e. from `setTitle()` in `onCreate()`.
 According to my knowledge `onCreate()` is the first method that is executed.

1. Now what I want is , I don't want this delay to be happened and activity should directly show the title from method i.e. Hello World .
2. I also want to know that why this delay occures and only title bar is shown first and rest GUI later.

Note: My condition is that I cant remove label from my `manifest.xml` file and still I want to do as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

just do this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setTitle("Hello World .");        
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


}
```

you need to decide to change title before loading layout

Answer (score 0):

The simple to display Hello world in title is

- Rename welcome to Hello world and no need to settitle on oncreate method

And the delay is due to loading the MainActivity .
First of xml data of the activity is loaded and then oncreate is called which calls its super class and then only settitle is called.